# iPhone - CC Avenue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing an iPhone application in which I need to pay for some bills. I need to use Electronic Fund Transfer(EFT) system to make the payment. Will apple accept my application if I use [CC Avenue](http://www.ccavenue.com/) for making the EFT? Is there any APIs available for integrating CC Avenue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an app that is going to be on the app store?

If so, you probably need to reach out directly to Apple's Developer Relations group and see what they say.  Apple usually wants to have their fingers in any financial transactions going through iOS.

I just looked on their [FAQ pages](http://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/) and they sure make it tough to find a good contact e-mail address.

Alternatively, instead of using CC Avenue (which I've never heard of), how about using a credit card processor that definitely has great iOS support... like [Square](https://squareup.com/).

Comment: Thank you Micheal. Surely will check it up with Square processing.